# How to set mock Geolocation Long/Lat in Python/Chromedriver/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I'm running Python/Chromedriver/GoogleChrome/Selenium headless
on python, and I am having some trouble figuring out how to set a custom geolocation long / lat programmatically; the following code is not updating location on google.com or https://www.infobyip.com/browsergeolocation.php

At the moment I'm starting chromedriver with these options:

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", { 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 1, 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 1,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 1, 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1,
    "profile.default_content_settings.geolocation": 1,
    "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0
  })
```

I can call and set/get the geolocation long / lat with these commands:

```
    driver.execute_script("""navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = function(success, failure) { 
      success({ 
        coords: {latitude: -43.5333, longitude: 172.633}, 
        timestamp: Date.now(), 
      }); 
    }"""); 
    time.sleep(5) 
    print(driver.execute_script("var positionStr=\"\";"+ 
                                "window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){positionStr=pos.coords.latitude+\":\"+pos.coords.longitude});"+
                                "return positionStr;"))
```

This does return the updated long / lat that I have set.
BUT when using https://www.infobyip.com/browsergeolocation.php or http://google.com, it does not grab the new geolocation and does not work.

How would one set a custom geolocation with chromedriver config arguments, chrome dev tools programmatically, or by modifying files in my chrome's profile directory? The other answers for pythons selenium on stack overflow do not seem to work here.

Comment: this is not programmatical - but have you try the Chrome developer - sensors and change the location ?

Comment: Yes I have and it works, thats what I'm currently looking into. sorry to re-phrase the question slightly, but does anyone know how to set a custom mock sensor location from python/selenium/chromedriver using the chromes remote devtools?

Comment: I've been able to connect to the remote devtools debugger via socketio,
I send this:
{
      "id": 5,
      "method": "Emulation.setGeolocationOverride",
      "params": {
     "latitude": 27.1752868,
     "longitude": 78.040009,
     "accuracy": 100
      }
     }
and get the response: 
'{"id":5,"result":{}}'

I then change the page with:
{
      "id": 6,
      "method": "Page.navigate",
      "params": {
     "url": "https://www.infobyip.com/browsergeolocation.php"
      }
  }
But it still does not recognize the geolocation. Is this feature disabled in headless builds?

Comment: I still have not been able to get this to work

Comment: I ended up learning CDP and setting a mock geolocation with websockets and the chrome debug protocol. Their is a feature in chrome that lets you view the json request and responses of the cdp as it happens in devtools. Looking at what the actual protocol was doing as I interacted with it made it easier to find the required request and response formats to use in the actual product

Answer (score 5):

It's actually now progammable by using the Chrome Devtools Protocol (cdp):

```
params = {
    "latitude": 50.1109,
    "longitude": 8.6821,
    "accuracy": 100
}

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.setGeolocationOverride", params)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/maps')
```

Comment: It has no effect on google maps, as of 2022 Sepember, using Selenium 4, Python 3.10.7. 
Something like `curl ipconfig.io/json` seems to be deciding google maps geolocation.

Answer (score 0):

### Linux Distribution

#### Firefox Webdriver Selenium Version : 3.14.1

#### GeckoDriver : https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.26.0/geckodriver-v0.26.0-linux64.tar.gz

- Use the default Profile and modify it's settings
- Use profile with webdriver iteratively

#### Default profile , ex :  /home/-user-/.mozilla/firefox/wg8ugmge.default

#### Executable Path , ex : /home/-user-/Downloads/geckodriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('<path_to_default_profile>') 
profile.set_preference("geo.prompt.testing", True) 
profile.set_preference("geo.prompt.testing.allow", True)
profile.set_preference("geo.wifi.scan", True)
executable_path='<executable-path-geckodriver>'
profile.set_preference("geo.wifi.uri", 'data:application/json,{"location":{"lat":22.893,"lng":72.4095},"accuracy": 100.0}')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = executable_path , firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get('https://maps.mapmyindia.com')
```

Hope it solves your problem !