# Unable to mock the location of automated browser: pytest, selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pytest, splinter

I am using selenium, pytest, splinter and gherkins,

I have a test case where I want to mock the browser actual location and timezone.

I tried many approach like, executing js scripts and   emulating dev tools approach. But nothing works for me. Does anyone have idea or example where they have done so?

Comment: Selenium can most definitely accomplish this -- this answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58514585/how-to-set-mock-geolocation-long-lat-in-python-chromedriver-selenium

Comment: Tried it already, as I can see the sensors of the dev tools. That doesn't changed at all.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code successfully sets location and timezone for the web driver --

```
from selenium import webdriver

class Params:
    LOCATION = {
            "latitude": 25.2048,
            "longitude": 55.2708,
            "accuracy": 100,
        }

    TIMEZONE = {
        "timezoneId": "America/New_York"
        }

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Emulation.setGeolocationOverride", Params.LOCATION)
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Emulation.setTimezoneOverride", Params.TIMEZONE)

driver.get("https://my-location.org/") # Verify location
driver.get("https://webbrowsertools.com/timezone/") # Verify timezone
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It worked. I was setting the cdp_cmd command after opening the browser. I guess that was the problem.